# c++ reading file is too slow

Tags: c++, stream

I'm trying to to read ~36KB and it would take ~20 seconds to finish this loop:

```
ifstream input_file;

input_file.open("text.txt");
if( !(input_file.is_open()) )
{
    cout<<"File not found";
    exit(1);
}

std::string line;
stringstream line_stream;   //to use << operator to get words from lines

int lineNum=1;

while( getline(input_file,line) )   //Read file line by line until file ends
{
    line_stream.clear();    //clear stream
    line_stream << line;    //read line
    while(line_stream >> word)  //Read the line word by word until the line ends
    {
        //insert word into a linked list...
    }
    lineNum++;
}
input_file.close();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might, in fact, be your insertion into the linked list that is the problem.  It could be O(n^2), depending on how it is implemented.  And with 36kB, "`n`" could be big.

Comment: you are correct! I commented the insertion part and the code ended at the moment... I'll look for the problem now. thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

`stringstream::clear()` does not clear all context inside it. It only resets the error and EOF flags, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear.

The result is your `line_stream` accumulates all previous lines and the inner loop will run words over all the accumulated lines again and again.

So the total time you spend is about O(n^2) compared to O(n) of what you expect it to be.

Instead of using the same object across each line, you could define the new `line_stream` instance inside the while loop to have a brand new and also empty one. Like this:

```
fstream input_file;

input_file.open("text.txt");
if( !(input_file.is_open()) )
{
    cout<<"File not found";
    exit(1);
}

std::string line;

int lineNum=1;

while( getline(input_file,line) )   //Read file line by line until file ends
{
    stringstream line_stream;   // new instance, empty line.
    line_stream << line;    //read line
    while(line_stream >> word)  //Read the line word by word until the line ends
    {
        //insert word into a linked list...
    }
    lineNum++;
}
input_file.close();
```

Comment: another clean way to reset a string stream: `line_stream.str(std::string());`

Comment: So, you could just reset the stream with `line_stream.str(line);` and skip the `<<` insertion.

Comment: Thank you, but It reduced the time by ~4 seconds only,.. the whole code takes ~24 seconds.. this one takes ~20...

Comment: At that point it might be an issue where your storage bus is the problem? Do you have a lot of other I/O going on? (And even though the file is small, have you checked that it is concurrent on the drive?)

Comment: Yeah I figured out that the class insertion member function is the one taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt the following:

```
std::ifstream file("text.txt");
std::string str;

while (std::getline(file, str))
{
    cout << str; //call function to to retrieve words of str in memory not in file 
}
```

I ran your code in 11ms, but with the mentioned option in 8ms. May be it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with build flag `-O2` or `-O3`.

> I was surprised to see that a simple for-loop to read a 1GB file took 4.7 seconds, whereas another higher level language (Dart) did it in 3.x seconds.
>
> After enabling this flag, runtime dropped to 2.1 seconds.